# Where to find rotten flesh in 7 Days to Die Alpha 18?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

Ever since Alpha 18, gardening hoes have been removed and farming now requires the building of farm plots. One requirement to craft them is rotten flesh.

Now it should not be too hard to find rotten flesh in a game where the vast majority of enemies are rotting people, but I can't find a way to gain rotten flesh from dead zombies.

How can I reliably find rotten flesh?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've found 3 reliable sources:

- Killing and skinning zombified animals with a knife
- Attacking the [animal gore](https://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Animal_Gore) ("rib cages") you find on roads
- Destroying body bags

Comment: It seems only zombified animals yield rotten meat. Wolves, Deer, Boars and non-zombified Bear only yield regular meat.

Comment: Correct. Edited my comment to clarify.

Comment: And body bags have a little

Answer (score 9):

The following may be a spoiler, but there is one location which contains a high amount of rotten flesh.

> If you travel east from the pine forest trader, you'll come to a crossroads. Turn south in the small town past the pawn shop, then east again and follow the dirt road. Once you hit the next larger street, turn north and you will find Carl's Corn and Bob's Boars. This area has *a lot* of decaying corpses around, as well as other loot.
>  This area also contains a secret area, with more corpses. The high amount of dead bodies could be an indicator as to what you may expect there.

Keep in mind that the game resets a location if you activate a quest related to that location (e.g. a fetch quest, etc.), which allows you to loot the location again before the reset timer expired.

Comment: I already noticed that boars have been buffed. One shot of a blunderbuss, one power attack with a steel sledgehammer and two normal attacks and it's still not dead.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade SE. If your answer contains spoilers, you may want to include them in a [spoiler tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers).

Comment: Meta post regarding the current edit to this answer: [Why was this edit rejected?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14703/4797) I have a post there explaining why I disagree with the current edit to the answer. I don't think hiding most of the answer under spoiler markup is necessary nor is the rewording done to most of the answer.

Comment: Just note that the game also has dynamic map generation, so the "spoiler" is only relevant in the pre-built "default" map. There are actually unique map sections for both pre-generated and dynamic maps that do not appear in the other. Plus the game is still in Beta (has been for years though).

Answer (score 6):

The only reliable method I've found so far is from butchering zombified animals (birds, dogs, bears, etc). Human zombies do not appear to give any flesh.

It can also be found randomly in containers, but I haven't noticed whether any particular type is more likely to contain it.